What are these muhurtas?
Haribhaktivilāsa, quoting Hayaśīrṣapañcarātra states

मैत्रे वैराजसावित्रे श्वेते वा वासवे शिवे । अभिजिद्रोहिणीनाञ्च मुहूर्ते पद्मसम्भवे । गान्धर्वे वा स्थापयेत् हरिं सुरगणार्चितम् ।।
Translation: O Lotus-born one ! One must perform the consecration of the image of Hari adorned by the host of devas in the muhūrtas of Mitra, Vairāja, Sāvitra, Śveta, Vāsava, Śiva, Abhijit, Rohiṇi & Gandharva.

A search through the Internet revealed that the muhūrtas named Mitra, Abhijit & Rohiṇī are respectively the 3rd, 8th & 9th ones after sunrise & the muhūrta named Śiva may be the 1st one after sunrise (called Rudra). Does anybody know what parts of the day does the other muhūrtas named Vairāja, Sāvitra, Śveta, Vāsava & Gāndharva occupy ?

A day i.e. time between sunrise and sunset is divided into 15 parts which is known as muhūrta :

śāntiparva CCXXXI : Thirty muhūrtas make up one day and night.

the names & sequence of these muhūrtas, in context of astrological predictions, are given in atharvedīya jyotiṣa (part of vedānga) - link :

त्ररीनांत्‌ भवेत्‌ त्रिशान्म्‌दहतंस्य प्रयाजनम्‌ द्रादशांगृलमुच्छषं
तस्य छाया प्रमाणतः ।५।
नवत्ति षडंगुलाश्चेव प्रतीचीं तां प्रकाशयेत्‌। पुरस्तात्‌ सन्धि वेलायां
मुहर्तों रोद्रउच्यते ।६।
श्वेतः षष्टिः समाख्यातो मेत्रोवे द्ादशांगुलः। षट्‌ सुसारभरोसतेयः सावित्रः पञ्चसुस्मृतः ।७।
चतुष्‌ चेव वैराजस्त्रिघ्‌ विश्वावस्‌ स्तथा मध्याह
चाभिजिन्नाम यस्मिन्‌ छाया प्ररत्रिष्ठत्ति ।८।
प्राचीं वेनामिनीं छायां रौहिणस्त्रिषु वर्त॑ते। बलश्चतुषु
विख्यातो विजयः पञ्चसु स्मृतः ।९।
नेऋतस्त्‌, घडंगुल्यो वारुणो द्वादशांग्‌लः। सौम्यः षष्ठिः समाख्यातो भगस्तु परमस्तथा । ९०।

Other Reference - https://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/02-08/editorials2532.htm
